# How to remove the gaps disappear vertically among images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use flex to align the images loaded from database, but the heights are determined by the highest images each line, how can I remove the gap vertically?

[image]

```
.imgs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items:center;
    align-content:flex-start;
    justify-content: space-around;
 }
```

Comment: Use,**float: left** them as they need to be next to one another. An added benefit of making <img>s display: block is that the mysterious bottom margin disappears as well.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/